# Remapping multiple keypresses in Vimium

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, vimium

I am trying to use vimium to simulate a list of vimium keystrokes

unmap 9
unmap 0
map 9 fswfsw

map 0 fswfaw

so if I type ‘9’ in Chrome, it should activate vimium by typing ‘f’ ’sw’ ‘f’ ’sw'

My use case is that I am watching videos using a Kaltura video player and I can't seem to find a keyboard shortcut to toggle the captions, however I see in Vimium that I can turn on the captions by pressing (fswfsw) and turn off the captions (fswfaw).

Can anyone assist with what I am doing wrong??

FYI: I'm not attached to the numbers '0' and '9' (or even Vimium if there is a better way) they can be any key.